# removing special charactets from string and add more if string is of certain length in python

Tags: python, string, file, formatting

i am reading .txt and .log extension files having entries below

$AV:3666,0000,0*

$AV:3664,0000,0*

but i want to remove extra characters and symbols (AV....0000,0*)so that i can have an entry like this

$:2226

$:2308

how can i go about it in python,below is the code i am using

`source_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\file1'`

`file_formats = ['.txt','.log']`

```
filenames = []
for filename in os.listdir():
 for file_format in file_formats:
     if filename.endswith(file_format):
         filenames.append(filename)
```

will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my beutiful regex

```
import re
x = "$AV:3664,0000,0*"
line = re.sub('[AV,0000,0*]', '', x)
```

It's just amazing.
Look at this spottles output.

```
$:3664
```

Comment: If so, leave a check mark. It's quite motivating.